# KeyError: 'image'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

When I trying to save detail, I have this error: KeyError: 'image'. I can't understand, why? Error in views.py. I want to upload multiple photos at once

views.py:

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_superuser)
def new_detail(request):
ImageFormSet = modelformset_factory(DetailImage,
                                    form=ImageForm, extra=10)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = DetailForm(request.POST)
    formset = ImageFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES,
                           queryset=DetailImage.objects.none())

    if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
        detail_form = form.save()
        detail_form.save()
        for form in formset.cleaned_data:
            images = form['image'] # HERE IS THE PROBLEM
            photo = DetailImage(detail=detail_form, image=images)
            photo.save()
        return redirect('/new_detail/')
else:
    form = DetailForm(request.POST)
    formset = ImageFormSet(queryset=DetailImage.objects.none())
return render(request, 'shop/new_detail.html',
{'form': form,'formset': formset})
```

forms.py

```
...
class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
image = forms.ImageField()
class Meta:
    model = DetailImage
    fields = ('image',)
```

models.py

```
...
class DetailImage(models.Model):
detail = models.ForeignKey(Detail, related_name='images',
on_delete=models.CASCADE)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='details', null = True, blank = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

KeyError: 'image' in your case means that there is no 'image' key in one of the forms in your formset cleaned data. You should perform a check. Something like this:

```
    for form in formset.cleaned_data:
        if 'image' in form:
            image = form['image']
            photo = DetailImage(detail=detail_form, image=image)
            photo.save()
```

Comment: Iareanon, this does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).